# Design using float: right and left. USE CASE

Tags: html, css, css-float

I would like to get your advices about the design of a header of my webpage.

***The general structure of its design is shown below:***

[image: Header of the website]

***Its HTML part:***

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="logo1"></div>
   <div class="logo2"></div>
</div>
```

***Its CSS part:***

```
.header{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 160px;
   border: 1px solid #48ace1;   
}

.logo1{
   float: left;
   width: 655px;
   height: 160px;
   background: url(images/logo1.png) no-repeat 0px 2px;  
}

.logo2{
   float: right;
   width: 465px;
   height: 160px;
   background: url(images/logo2.png) no-repeat 0px 2px;
   position: relative; /* it is set to relative because inside this layer I have 
                          several elements with absolute position.*/
}
```

**The problem:**

When I open this webpage in a computer with a wide screen it opens perfectly, without any problems, but when I open it with a computer with a small-width screen the second logo (`.logo2`) falls down to the next line as shown in the following figure:

[image: Header with a browser with a small width]

This happens because totaly the width of `.logo1` and `.logo2` is `655px+465px=1120px`. So, once the width of the browser is less then 1200px more or less, the second logo (`.logo2`)  couldn't find place inside the `.header` and it automatically falls down to the next line.

In such a cases, I want `.logo2` to overlap `.logo1` if the width of the browser is less then the total width of two logos (`.logo1` and `.logo2`, in my case more or less 1200px). How can I achieve this affect? Note, that I need `.logo1` to be justified to the left-hand and `.logo2` to be justified to the right-hand.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use float? You're halfway to using CSS positioning with that `position:absolute;`! http://jsfiddle.net/6sFY5/1/

Comment: What did you mean by that Richard?

Comment: My comment? I had to edit my answer; comment was meant as an explanation of the edit in case you took a peak before I edited it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use absolute positioning:

http://jsfiddle.net/LuRDk/

```
.header{
    position:relative;
    height:84px;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid green;
}

.logo{
    position:absolute;
    width:80px;
    height: 80px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.right{right:20px;}
.left{left:20px;}
```

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo left"></div>
    <div class="logo right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a negative margin to logo1, like so:

```
.logo1
{
    float: left;
    width: 655px;
    margin-right: -655px;
    height: 160px;
    background: url(images/logo1.png) no-repeat 0px 2px;  
}
```

This will mean the window can get as narrow as possible, and logo2 will never drop down.

*Edited, since first try would still make logo 2 drop at width less than 655px.*

**Edit 2:** You can also set a z-index on .logo2 so that it will cover logo1, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="logo1"></div>
   <div class="logo2"></div>
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is an old solution to make #header contain the floats, but that is not what the OP was asking. The header already has a height.